# SQL Server based on current date need to check the date range in WHERE condition

Tags: sql-server

Based on current date, I need to set case in `WHERE` condition.

```
select 
    count(id) 
from 
    table1
case 
   when (DAY(GETDATE())) between 1 and 15 
      Then created_date between (getdate()-DAY(GETDATE())+1) and (getdate()+15-DAY(GETDATE()))
   else created_date between (getdate()+16-DAY(GETDATE())) and (getdate()+31-DAY(GETDATE()))
  End
```

but it does not work for me.

For eg,

Table1:

```
Id   App_Name  Created_Date
1     app1     2016-12-05
2     app2     2016-12-10
3     app3     2016-12-16
4     app4     2016-12-25
5     app5     2016-12-28
```

Today date is 2016-12-15, So i need to take created_date between 2016-12-01 to 2016-12-15.

Expected output is "2"

Comment: But why would `2016-12-05` not be included in the result set since it is within range?

Comment: 2016-12-05 also included. first 2 records will be taken for the count.

Comment: What's your requirement in plain English? Are you counting records from the start of month to current date?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a nested `CASE` expression along with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DAY(GETDATE()) <= 15 THEN
            SUM(CASE WHEN created_date BETWEEN (getdate()-DAY(GETDATE())+1) AND
                                               (getdate()+15-DAY(GETDATE()))
                     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            ELSE
            SUM(CASE WHEN created_date BETWEEN (getdate()+16-DAY(GETDATE())) AND
                                               (getdate()+31-DAY(GETDATE()))
                     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       END AS summary
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way of doing it.Working perfectly.Try it once

```
SELECT CASE 
     WHEN (DAY(GETDATE())) < 16 THEN
        (Select Count(1) from SEP_RetailStore WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE DAY(CreateDate) BETWEEN 1 and 15)
        ELSE (Select Count(1) from SEP_RetailStore WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE DAY(CreateDate) >= 16)
     END
```